# How to change the layout orientation of simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have one application where i have to check the application in both the landscape and portrait orientations. I can do this, by tilting the device. But how i can i perform this in Emulator.

Comment: Num 7 is working but Ctrl + F11  is not working

Comment: left Ctrl+F11 should work (right - doesn't on Windows)

Comment: Ya thank u Style i got it thank u very much for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>7</kbd> on the Numpad and turn off Numlock before doing that.

Answer (score 4):

You can rotate the emulator by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> *(or <kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad)*.
See the [emulator keyboard mapping](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping).

Answer (score 3):

7 & 9 on the keypad or Ctrl+F11 & Ctrl+F12

Answer (score 3):

If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, it will rotate

Answer (score 1):

switch off the "Num Lock" on ur keyboard and now press "7" below the num lock to change the orientation of emulator.

Answer (score 1):

just turn of the num lock and press 7 to change the orientation of the simul